# humanize "naturaltime" issue

Tags: django, django-templates

I've got this strange problem where the humanize filters aren't working in one template, but work fine in another with exactly the same data. `django.contrib.humanize` has been added to my `INSTALLED_APPS` and the variable im calling `naturalday` on is a str which contains a ISO date without the time element e.g `2013-06-27`

I can't figure out why it works in one template and not the other with exactly the same data. Instead the template instead just prints out the string contents.

Here's the template in question:

```
 {% extends "base.html" %} {% load i18n %} {% load humanize %} {% block
 content %}

 <div class="large-7 columns">{% autoescape off %}
             <a href="{{ product.offerUrl }}" target="_blank">{{ product.img }}</a>
             {% endautoescape %}</div> {% if product.affiliate == 'no' %}<div class="large-12 columns main-posted">Posted:  {{
 product.dateAdded|naturalday }}</div>{% endif %}
```